# Spring Data. Проекция

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-jpa

при выводе метода "List findAllUserName();"

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
    // getter setter toString()
}

public interface UserName {
    String getName();
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query(value="select u.name as name from User u", nativeQuery=True)
    List<UserName> findAllUserName();
```

Получаю такой ответ:

```
interface java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler,org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy@3c5e03c7,public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode(),public boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object),public abstract String ru.project.models.UserName.getName()
```

Как сделать что бы он выводил только getName(), а не этот список. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Поясните, что значит `при выводе метода "List findAllUserName()"`?

Comment: у вас в репозитории List<UserName>, а запрашиваете вы select u.name , это значит, что вы пытаетесь затолкать коллекцию стрингов в коллекцию UserName. поэтому у вас летит исключение. поменяйте  List<UserName> на  List<String> в репозитории

Comment: А если в интерфейсе UserName 2 и более параметров? ну и в селекте соответственно тоже

Comment: @Sergey в целом , если у вас есть необходимость составлять подобные запросы, то посмотрите в сторону Spring JdbcTemplate, потому как дальше пойдут join и т.д. а в целом большое количество таких запросов говорит о том, что архитектура вашего приложения оставляет желать лучшего